# Возможно ли привязывать функции к std::function без использования placeholders?

Tags: c++, c++11

Раньше я использовал библиотеку [fastdelegate](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible) для указателей на функции класса (делегаты). Но, поскольку в стандарте C++11 появился класс `std::function`, я подумал, что в дополнительной библиотеке больше нет необходимости.

Раньше я писал так:

```
fastdelegate::FastDelegate3<const std::string&, int64_t, AbstractImage*> onFrameGrabbed;
onFrameGrabbed.bind(this, &CVideoGrabberPage::OnFrameGrabbed);
```

C std::function приходится писать так:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
std::function<void(const std::string&, int64_t, AbstractImage*)> onFrameGrabbed;
onFrameGrabbed = std::bind( &CVideoGrabberPage::OnFrameGrabbed, this, _1, _2, _3);
```

Однако, это утомительно.
Можно ли привязывать функции класса не указывая placeholders для всех аргументов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::bind` является генератором функциональных объектов и он должен знать, что ему нужно использовать при генерации, поэтому — нет, либо используйте `placeholders`, либо актуальные значения, либо пишите свой класс(это будет довольно просто), т.к. без явного указания аргументов эта задача не решается. В Вашем первом примере, `FastDelegate3` знает свои аргументы, т.к. Вы задаёте их явно, только так эта задача в C++ и решается.